# How to decrease buffer size in vlcj

Tags: buffer, media-player, vlc, vlcj

I need to make a player for RTSP streams using vlcj, anyway it buffers too much time (cameras are some seconds late), how can I reduce the buffers/delay to 1 second or less.

It's a few time I'm browsing the javadocs for vlcj 4.7.3 But I'm not able to find any control for the buffers.

I'm using Java11 + JFX17

code to play a video

```java
private ImageView videoImageView = new ImageView();
private EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

private MediaPlayerFactory factory;

[...]
        factory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
        mediaPlayer = factory.mediaPlayers().newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

        var vs = new ImageViewVideoSurface(this.videoImageView);
        mediaPlayer.videoSurface().set(vs);
        videoImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        this.node = videoImageView

        mediaPlayer.media().play("c:\\tmp\\test.mp4");
        mediaPlayer.controls().start();
        mediaPlayer.audio().setMute(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for example:

```java
factory = new MediaPlayerFactory("--network-caching=1000");
```

There is also live-caching, file-caching and so on.

The available options come from `vlc -H | grep cach`.