# Open RTP stream in JPanel using VlcJ

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, rtp, vlcj

I have a java swing app and im trying to display an rtp stream running on the same machine. I have tried using the ip adress or the sdp file with no luck.

```
public class MediaPlayer {
    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean playing;
    public MediaPlayer(JPanel parent) {
        new NativeDiscovery().discover();
        EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerComponent.mediaPlayer();
        parent.add(mediaPlayerComponent, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public void Play() {
        this.playing = true;
        this.mediaPlayer.controls().play();
    }
    public void Stop() {
        this.playing = false;
        this.mediaPlayer.controls().stop();
    }

    public void setMedia(String activeCam) {
        String p1 = "src/placeholders/fish.mp4";
        String p2 = "src/placeholders/rat.mp4";
        String s1 = "rtp://127.0.0.1:2222";
        switch (activeCam) {
            case "Cam1":
                this.mediaPlayer.media().startPaused("rtp://127.0.0.1:2222");
                break;
            case "Cam2":
                this.mediaPlayer.media().startPaused(p2);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `setMedia("Cam2")` and later `Play()` will display the video, but calling `setMedia("Cam1")` and `Play()` afterwards will bring only a blackscreen. I am able to open the video stream using the sdp file in vlc.
This is the command used to stream the camera
`ffmpeg -hide_banner -f dshow -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 15 -i video="Logitech BRIO" -b:v 5500k  -an -f rtp rtp://localhost:2222?pkt_size=800 -sdp_file stream.sdp`

Im expecting the Video feed to switch from the video and show the live stream but no luck,
i have tried using the `rtp://localhost:2222`, `rtp://@:2222`, the sdp file and no luck

Comment: Why do you use startPaused on your live stream? Did you try just play() instead?

Comment: Also try adding "-vvv" to the media player factory initialisation and check the logs when you play your live feed.

Comment: @caprica idk what changed on my setup but doing `play()` with the sdp file now works, the feed is now being displayed although the latency is not that good, is there a way to disable buffering or to at least lower the amount of buffer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318693/how-to-decrease-buffer-size-in-vlcj